# Target specific variables with Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm setting up deployment pools and release pipelines for my application in Azure devops.  For my release, I'll have 3 stages: Dev, QA, and Prod.  I see how I can take my variable group and apply it to a stage, which has a deployment pool assigned to it.  That's great.

The confusing part is that, as an example,  I have 3 servers(targets) in my Dev deployment pool, and they have different variables needed for each (different connection strings).  I don't know how to make the variables target specific, rather than stage specific.

Should I abandon the idea of grouping my Dev servers into 1 Dev deployment group, and just separate them out?  Like make a Dev1 group, and a Dev2 group, and then  make a Dev1 stage and Dev2 stage, etc?  Or is there a better way I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment groups in azure devops share the same configuration settings. Basically your dev servers are different environments so i guess the best approach is to have different deployment groups for every different server.

Comment: i was hoping for a different answer honestly.  The main reason i asked this question was to avoid this solution, seems like there should be a better way.